# Match the substring that starts from the last capital letter word that is not in parenthesis to the end of the string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need the substring that matches from with the last leading (first in word) capital letter that is not within parenthesis to the end of string

I tried to use this regex:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z\-\']*\s*)*(\s+\([^)]*\)[\s]*)+$
```

to match this input:

```
can This Be PosSible (Ignore aNy Upper CAse in parenthesis)
```

and the match is:

```
This Be PosSible (Ignore aNy Upper CAse in parenthesis)
```

but the desired output is:

```
PosSible (Ignore aNy Upper CAse in parenthesis)
```

See [this on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iO7uO5/1).

Comment: @ndn I want the first capital letter word starting from the end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for your example:

```
\b[A-Z](?![^(]*\))(?!.*\b[A-Z](?![^(]*\))).*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/IJDT6j4QBv).

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a uppercase letter in the last word. Try to match this "we cant do this BecAuse". The match is "Ause", it should be "BecAuse". Can you suggest an alternative

Comment: @lederp sure, easy - add word boundary. See edit and new demo link.